# Make text only take up existing space?

Tags: html, css

I have a containing div with styling. I need this div to wrap around an image and text content not taking up more space than necessary.

When I just have an image this is easy enough: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXQyzr

```
.cont {
  text-align: center;
}
.cont2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont2">
     <div class="image">
        <img width="400" src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg" />
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I have text, the text expands to take up the full width: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvOvqL

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont2">
     <div class="image">
        <img width="400" src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="text">
        <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text        </p>
     </div>
   </div>  
</div>
```

[image]

My layout is responsive and the content is dynamic and the size of the image (which dictates the size of the container) will vary. As such I cant set a fixed width on anything.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you need. Can't you just float your img?

Comment: I want the image above the text which is the opposite of what floats normally achieve?

Comment: You want to confine the text to be just within the boundary of the img?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/PqjPWy)**

```
.cont2 {

  border: 3px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue; 
  color:white;
  width: 1%;
  display: table;
  margin:auto;

}
.text{
  display: inline-block;     
}
```

Comment: Will it work without hardcoding any width at all except on original container? In cases where I do not specify image width and let it be the original size.

Comment: Content width totally depends on img width.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```css
.cont {
  text-align: center;
}
.cont2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
  position:relative;
  
}
.text{
  position:absolute;
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
    left:-3px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont2">
  <div class="image">
    <img width="400" src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg" />
  </div>
    <div class="text">
    <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider removing the width attribute from the image and make it fully responsive using css. From there you can let .text conform to the max-width of the image i.e. providing you know or can supply the dimensions of your images.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvOQOq

Also, consider converting your pixel values to ems for scalability (desired width/app font-size). e.g. if app default font-size is 16px, then image width 400px = 400/16 = 25em.

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont2">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text </div>
  </div>
</div>  
</div>

.cont {
  text-align: center;
}

.cont2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.image img {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: The width attribute I set for demo purposes as the actual image I used is very large. This is a good solution accept that I need the max width to be the actual width of the image, not an arbitrary value like 400px;

Comment: if you're using php, you can always use getimagesize and set the width inline on the image e.g. 
$img_s = getimagesize($file); 
$img_w = $img_s[0]; 

style="width: <?php echo $img_w/16;?>em;"

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with display table:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqjPPB

```
<div class="con3">
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont2">
  <div class="image">
    <img width="400" src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text </div>
  </div>
</div>  
</div>
</div>

.con3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.cont {
  display: inline-block;
}
.cont2 {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
  display: table;
  width: 1px;
}
.image {
  display: table-row;
}
.text {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution #1

Set `width: min-content` on the container div

### [Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/zGzvzo)

```css
.cont {
  text-align: center;
}
.cont2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont2">
    <div class="image">
      <img width="400" src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="text">
      <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some
        text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### Solution #2:

1) Set `display:table` on the container: and

2) Set `display: table-caption;` with `caption-side: bottom;` on the text

### [Codepen](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/YXQyev)